# Handling large percentage of zero-valued observations in a continuous dependent variable in a panel dataset

Tags: r, panel-data, stata, zero-inflation

I am writing a paper using a panel dataset in which my depepent variable is continuous has an large percentage amount of zero values observations. Those zero values are real zeros, I mean they are not missing data or whatsoever. I have taken a look on the literature and there are many models that can be applied in this case. I am awared of the following: Tobit (Tobin, 1958), Two-Stage Model (Heckman, 1979), Two-Parts Model (Duan et al.,1984), PPML (Silva & Tenreyro, 2006) and Double-Hurdle models (Dong & Kaiser, 2008). Which one should I use and how to justify the adoption?

Comment: Cross-posted, with several answers, at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1522741-handling-large-percentage-of-zero-valued-observations-in-the-dependent-variable-in-a-panel-dataset Telling people about cross-posting is a good idea.